# Is it possible to calculate the half-life of a nucleus?

Tags: nuclear-physics, radiation

Is it possible to calculate theoretically the half life of a nucleus (how?) or they are all known through measurements? As an example how do you calculate the half life of Carbon-14?

Comment: In detail from first principles? I don't think so, but there are some passing decent heuristics.

Comment: I mean is nuclear theory advanced enough to be able to predict the half life of a nucleus ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, it has not been shown definitively to be possible or impossible, but at the very least, it is not known how to do it.

The fabled [island of stability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Island_of_stability) is an active area of research in nuclear science. The existence of the very island is a prediction based on the [nuclear shell hypothesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_shell_model), which is known to have problems. For example, as mentioned on the first wikipedia page, there is at least one element (Hassium-270) which is predicted to be "stable" by the theory and the latest insights, but it is not.

In conclusion -- in the current state of the art, we can't even predict whether nuclei are "stable" or not, let alone  quantify exactly *how* stable they are . The best we can do now is [collect stamps](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Ernest_Rutherford) :)

Comment: OK thanks a lot. If you have have any references...

Comment: @Anarchasis: I have colleagues in the field, and their friends :) I'm not as familiar with this as I would like, so my familiarity with the scientific literature on this subject is minimal. In any case, there are some keywords in my answer to facilitate initial searches.